# Add sound when image changes

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

This is my attempt: when the button is pressed a different random image appears(this part works).  What I can't get to work is the other part I'd like it do to.  Depending on which image appears will depend on what soundbite is played.  i.e. if the image is a black car, there are 2 separate files that'll play; one that says black and the other will say car.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Here's my code:

```
public class Black extends Activity {
    ImageView imageView;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    int sound=525,sound1=525;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.black);
      Button Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
      Button1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
          public void onClick(View v){
           onClickImageView(v);
          }
      });
    }

   public void onClickImageView(View view) {

       int[] picture= {
        R.drawable.black,R.drawable.blackairplane,R.drawable.blackbear,R.drawable.blackcar,R.drawable.blackcircle,
            R.drawable.blackkite,R.drawable.blacksquare,R.drawable.blacktriangle};
        Random r = new Random();
        int n=r.nextInt(7);
        imageView.setImageResource(picture[n]);

        switch (picture[n]) {
         case R.drawable.black: 
              sound = R.raw.sayblack;
              sound1 = R.raw.sayblack;
              break;

         case R.drawable.blackairplane: 
              sound = R.raw.sayblack;
              sound1= R.raw.sayairplane;
              break;

         case R.drawable.blackbear:
             sound = R.raw.sayblack;
             sound1 = R.raw.saybear;
             break;

         case R.drawable.blackcar: 
                  sound = R.raw.sayblack;
                  sound1= R.raw.saycar;
                  break;

         case R.drawable.blackcircle: 
              sound = R.raw.sayblack;
              sound1=R.raw.saycircle;
              break;

         case R.drawable.blackkite: 
              sound = R.raw.sayblack;
              sound1 = + R.raw.saykite;
              break;

         case R.drawable.blacksquare: 
              sound = R.raw.sayblack;
              sound1 =  R.raw.saysquare;
              break;

         case R.drawable.blacktriangle: 
              sound = R.raw.sayblack;
              sound1= R.raw.saytriangle;
              break;
        }

        if(mp!=null){
         mp.release();
        }
        if(sound!=0){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), sound);
          mp.start();

        }


         mp.setOnCompletionListener (new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){

         @Override
          public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           if(sound1!=0 && sound!=0){
           mp= MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),sound1);
           mp.start();
           sound=sound1=525;
           }}
         });

        }
}
```

and here's my .xml file:

```
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
       android:background="@color/white"
       android:text="@string/black" />

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="@string/black" />
```

... and this is the correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following code

```
public class Black extends Activity {
     ImageView imageView;
     MediaPlayer mp;

     int sound=525,sound1=525;


     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.black);
       Button Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
       imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
       Button1.setOnClickListner( new OnClickListener(){
           public void onClick(view v){
            onClickImageView(v);
           }
       });
     }

    public void onClickImageView(View view) {

        int[] picture= {
         R.drawable.black,R.drawable.blackairplane,R.drawable.blackbear,R.drawable.blackcar,R.drawable.blackcircle,R.drawable.blackkite,R.drawable.blacksquare,R.drawable.blacktriangle};
         Random r = new Random();
         int n=r.nextInt(7);
         imageView.setImageResource(picture[n]);

         switch (picture[n]) { //here is the change in code
          case R.drawable.black: 
               sound = R.raw.sayblack;
               break;

          case R.drawable.blackairplane: 
               sound = R.raw.sayblack ;
               sound1= R.raw.sayplane;
               break;

          case R.drawable.blackcar: 
                   sound = R.raw.sayblack;
                   sound1= R.raw.saycar;
                   break;

          case R.drawable.blackcircle: 
               sound = R.raw.sayblack ;
               sound1=R.raw.saycircle;
               break;

          case R.drawable.blackkite: 
               sound = R.raw.sayblack ;
               sound1 = + R.raw.saykite;
               break;

          case R.drawable.blacksquare: 
               sound = R.raw.sayblack ;
               sound1 =  R.raw.saysquare;
               break;

          case R.drawable.blacktriangle: 
               sound = R.raw.sayblack ;
               sound1= R.raw.saytriangle;
               break;
         }

         if(mp!=null){
          mp.release();
         }
         if(sound!=0){
         mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), sound);
           mp.start();

         }


          mp.setOnCompletionListener (new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){

          @Override
           public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(sound1!=0 && sound!=0){
            mp= MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),sound1);
            mp.start();
            sound=sound1=525;
            }}
          });

         }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

change button as following in ur xml (REmove onclick att from xml and do it dynamically at runtime in java code), i can see errors in the onclick of button view, now this code will surely work

```
<Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
       android:background="@color/white"
       android:text="@string/black" 
       />
```

Comment: you forgot to add if ( mp != null ) {mp.stop();} before mp.start() to prevent duplicate sounds ;)

Comment: I made the changes you suggested.  It's still not working, and I've posted the Logcat file.  Any ideas? (cause I'm lost)

Comment: there was an error:    The constructor MediaPlayer(Context, int) is undefined;  referring to the line:   mp= new MediaPlayer(getBaseContext(),sound1);.     I tried to define it but it wasn't being recognized.

Comment: I'm getting the same result.  I'm running it through both an AVD and my phone with the same outcome...only audio for every image is "black"

Comment: Your doing something else that I'm not than cause with the most recent code, when I press the button the app stops again.  I've updated my original .java code of what I've got as well as the Logcat with the error I'm getting.  Thanks for the help.  It is greatly appreciated as I have tried and researched as much as I can to try to figure this out for myself.

Comment: I've updated the error given in Logcat.  the app stopped itself again upon starting.

Comment: oh god .... interchange this two lines ...
Button Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
setContentView(R.layout.black);

so ur final code is as my updated answer ....

Answer (score 0):

You have one imageView and you are using its id in your switch cases. Your switch cases should be depends on your pictures not your imageViews id.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one `ImageView`, you can't use switch statement because your `ImageView` has unique id and always stays same.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
public class Black extends Activity {
    ImageView imageView;
    MediaPlayer mp;


    /* add this here */
    Context context;

    int sound=525,sound1=525;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.black);

      /* add this here */
      context = this;

      Button Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
      Button1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
          public void onClick(View v){
           onClickImageView(v);
          }
      });
    }

   public void onClickImageView(View view) {

       int[] picture= {
        R.drawable.black,R.drawable.blackairplane,R.drawable.blackbear,R.drawable.blackcar,R.drawable.blackcircle,
            R.drawable.blackkite,R.drawable.blacksquare,R.drawable.blacktriangle};
        Random r = new Random();
        int n=r.nextInt(7);
        imageView.setImageResource(picture[n]);

        switch (picture[n]) {
         case R.drawable.black: 
              sound = R.raw.sayblack;
              sound1 = R.raw.sayblack;
              break;

         case R.drawable.blackairplane: 
              sound = R.raw.sayblack;
              sound1= R.raw.sayairplane;
              break;

         case R.drawable.blackbear:
             sound = R.raw.sayblack;
             sound1 = R.raw.saybear;
             break;

         case R.drawable.blackcar: 
                  sound = R.raw.sayblack;
                  sound1= R.raw.saycar;
                  break;

         case R.drawable.blackcircle: 
              sound = R.raw.sayblack;
              sound1=R.raw.saycircle;
              break;

         case R.drawable.blackkite: 
              sound = R.raw.sayblack;
              sound1 = + R.raw.saykite;
              break;

         case R.drawable.blacksquare: 
              sound = R.raw.sayblack;
              sound1 =  R.raw.saysquare;
              break;

         case R.drawable.blacktriangle: 
              sound = R.raw.sayblack;
              sound1= R.raw.saytriangle;
              break;
        }

        //if still playing stop it 
        if( mp!=null && mp.isPlaying() ){

         mp.stop();
         mp.release();
         mp = null;

        }

         //play selected
          mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, sound);
          mp.start();




         mp.setOnCompletionListener (new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){

         @Override
          public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub



           if(sound1!=0 && sound!=0){
           mp= MediaPlayer.create(context,sound1);
           mp.start();
           sound=sound1=525;
           }}
         });

        }
}
```